# jQuery click not firing on asynchronously added elements

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, append

I've seen other questions that were supposed to answer mine, however for some reason, they did not. I am referring to these:
- [jquery click event not firing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540561/jquery-click-event-not-firing)
- [jquery functions dont work on dom elements loaded asynchromously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352853/jquery-functions-dont-work-on-dom-elements-loaded-asynchromously)

I first used click() to try to change the color of selected "li" to pink. It worked, but not for the "li"s appended dynamically.  I tried to use on() since live() is now deprecated.
I was surprised that it still did not work.

This is a sample that you can run:

**Javascript:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("ol").append("<li class='test'> Appended item </li>");
  });
});
</script>

<script>
$(function () {
  $('.test').on('click', function () {
    $(this).css("background-color","pink");
  });
});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
  <ol>
    <li class='test'> List item 1 </li>
    <li class='test'> List item 2 </li>
    <li class='test'> List item 3 </li>
  </ol>

  <button id="btn1">Append list item</button>
</body>
```

Does anyone have a clue?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use event [delegation](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events) based on [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('ol').on('click', '.test', function(el){
    $(this).css("background-color","pink");
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7CFCK/)