# jQuery File Upload not working when file input dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, blueimp

i am using this jquery uploader (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html) and it works fine when the file input is put in the raw code of the site, however i am dynamically appending the fields with jquery and it doesnt work. here is the jquery to trigger the upload:

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            alert(file.name);
            //$('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
        });
    }
});
```

and this is what SHOULD trigger the upload:

```
<input class="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="uploads/">
```

Here is the code that is appended by jquery:

```
$(document).on('click','.addItem', function(){
            $('<!--ROW START-->\
                <form class="widget-content item" data-url="uploads/">\
                    <div class="row">\
                        <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemName[]"></div>\
                        <div class="col-md-3"><textarea class="auto form-control" name="itemDescription[]" cols="20" rows="1" style="word-wrap: break-word; resize: vertical;"></textarea></div>\
                        <div class="col-md-3"><textarea class="auto form-control" name="itemCondition[]" cols="20" rows="1" style="word-wrap: break-word; resize: vertical;"></textarea></div>\
                        <input type="hidden" class="itemId" name="itemId[]" value="">\
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemInventoryId[]" value="<?=$_GET["inventory_id"]?>">\
                        <input type="hidden" name="itemParent[]" value="'+$(this).closest('.formHolder').data('parent-room')+'">\
                        <div class="col-md-2">\
                            <div class="fileinput-holder input-group">\
                                <input class="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]">\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class="col-md-1 align-center"><i class="save icon-ok large"> </i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="delete icon-trash large"> </i></div>\
                    </div>\
                </form>\
            <!--/ROW END-->').fadeIn(500).appendTo($(this).parents().siblings('.items'));
            $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.widget-header, .header-margin, .hide').removeClass('hide').fadeIn();
        });
```

like i say, when i add it into the actual code, not dynamically its fine. Can someone help please?

Comment: Usually this occurs when you call the $.fileUpload before the input element is appended to body. Try calling it after the element is created and appended.

Comment: I've popped it at the bottom of the document, no luck :(

Comment: ive added the code that gets appended, so you can see

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because you bind `fileupload` event before element is added.

Try moving your code into callback function which will be executed after you create input element. Since `appendTo()` [doesn't support callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113853/jquery-perform-callback-after-append), you can use `each(callback)`:

```
$('code_that_you_append').appendTo('some_element').each(function () {
    // here goes $('.fileupload').fileupload({ ... }) function
});
```

If you need to bind event to `.fileupload` in multiple places in code, you can create a function to avoid code repetition, like this:

```
function bindFileUpload() {
    $('.fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                alert(file.name);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

and then call it in the callback, like before:

```
$('code_that_you_append').appendTo('some_element').each(function () {
    bindFileUpload();
});
```

I've created a [little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LW9wt/). It binds `click` instead of `fileupload` to simplify things (fileupload is external plugin...), but the general rule stays the same.

Comment: Can you post example please?

Comment: Added. If you could post the jQuery code that you use to append your form, I'd be able to make my example more precise.

Comment: so it needs to go in with the code that i append? I'm adding multiple items so is this best practice?

Comment: Code has been added :)

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to avoid code repetition in case you need to bind this event in multiple places.

Comment: Does this bindFileUpload function go at the top or bottom of the page? I've placed it at the top and copied your code but it still doesnt fire

Comment: `function bindFileUpload() { ... }` can go at the top, as it is just a function definition. The rest of code (`$(document).on(...)` with callbacks inside) should go to the very bottom, just before closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Okay i've tried it, its literally doing nothing. It doesnt even load up anything in the console like it should

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39566/discussion-between-andy-holmes-and-michal-rybak)

Comment: sorry, I've been wrong - I didn't know that `appendTo` won't accept callback, that's why it wouldn't work. I've edited my answer and provided a simple demo, hope that helps.

Comment: Absolutely wonderful. Thank you so much, and thank you for coming back to this in your own time. You're a credit to the community friend, thank you!

Comment: I think this answer has little mistake. On my answer I am trying to explain that. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the jQuery live() function.

This tip I found worked for me.

[jQuery fileupload for dynamically added input field](http://www.dizkover.com/Programming/829/jquery-fileupload-for-dynamically-added-input-field)

Comment: If you can't get this solution to work, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540561/jquery-click-event-not-firing
I had to replace my "$('.class').on('click, function(e){" wrapper with "$(document).on('click', '.class', function(e){" so that it would examine every click event.

Answer (score 2):

Just bind the upload function with a static identifier at first. Here, 'document' is the static identifier. You can use anything like this that has not been added dynamically. Usually, document is used more often.

```
$(document).on('click', '.fileupload', function () {
    $('.fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                alert(file.name);
                //$('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This question is over 3 years old, the accepted answer worked fine

Answer (score 0):

**N.B: Please see accepted answer first.**

I think accepted answer has little mistake. I just trying to recover that.
On @Michał Rybak [little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LW9wt/) you will see that every time we click `add item` another click event also will be added to previous added `new link`( add more then  `new link` and see first `new link` show alert number of time `new item`). Because every time it add `new link` we again add click event to all `new link` elements.

```
 $('<p><a href="#" class="link">new link</a></p>').appendTo('body').each(function () {
      // bindClickToLink call every 'new link' and add click event on it
        bindClickToLink();
    });
```

To solve that issues, instead add click event to all item we just add to newly created item. Here is my solution [my demo](http://codepen.io/hasanuzzaman/pen/obzwYP) .